# Guzzle curl request getting empty response body but status is 200 and Content-Length header is correct

Tags: php, http, curl, guzzle

I am making a request through Guzzle 3.8.1 for a Jasper report (via the Jasper Server API) that is over 2MB and I'm getting a response with the correct Content-Length header but no response body.

Guzzle request:

```
GET /jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/projects/i3app_suite/Resource/BulkShiftExport.csv?ACCOUNT_ID=2&START_DATETIME=2015-01-01&END_DATETIME=2015-01-31 HTTP/1.1
Host: jasper.i3app:8080
User-Agent: Guzzle/3.8.1 curl/7.19.7 PHP/5.5.8
Authorization: Basic ***=
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: private
Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 17:00:00 MST
P3P: CP="ALL"
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=F0B0F72B65A8145B45DA9DB2BACE53D8; Path=/jasperserver/; HttpOnly, userLocale=en_US;Expires=Fri, 13-Feb-2015 18:56:44 GMT;HttpOnly
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="BulkShiftExport.csv"
output-final: true
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Content-Length: 2173897
Date: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 18:57:02 GMT
```

If I make this request through curl on the command line (or request it in a browser) I get the report as expected

```
GET /jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/projects/i3app_suite/Resource/BulkShiftExport.csv?ACCOUNT_ID=2&START_DATETIME=2015-01-01&END_DATETIME=2015-01-30 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic ***=
User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.15.3 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Host: jasper.i3app:8080
Accept: */*


< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Cache-Control: private
< Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 17:00:00 MST
< P3P: CP="ALL"
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AF1BF885354AF3E352DD9E18FA044A4B; Path=/jasperserver/; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: userLocale=en_US;Expires=Fri, 13-Feb-2015 19:03:42 GMT;HttpOnly
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="BulkShiftExport.csv"
< output-final: true
< Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
< Content-Length: 2113902
< Date: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 19:03:49 GMT
< 
{ [data not shown]
```

The only difference I could see was `Accept: */*` in the curl request. I tried adding that header to the guzzle request and got the same result.

When making the request through the Guzzle client it appears to take the same amount of time (5-6 seconds) to receive the response, and it sets the Content-Length header, but the response body is empty. Why am I getting an empty response body though Guzzle which is using curl but not when using curl on the command line? Is there an option I need to set to make this work?

```
    $request = $this->getGuzzleClient()->createRequest('GET');

    $config = $this->getConfig();
    $url = new Url(
        $config['scheme'],
        $config['host'],
        $config['user'],
        $config['pass'],
        $config['port'],
        $config['path'] . $reportPath . '.' . $format,
        new QueryString($parameters)
    );
    $request->setUrl($url);

    $response = $request->send();
```

...

```
public function getGuzzleClient()
{
    if (!$this->restClient) {
        $client = new GuzzleClient();
        $this->setRestClient($client);
    }
    return $this->restClient;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the user-agent: `$client->setHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36');`

Comment: @halfer That is how curl command line tool outputs it when I use -v (verbose) flag

Comment: @halfer I'm using jasper's REST api to retrieve the report. The report works fine using the jasperserver ui, and when I hit the url through the browser or curl on the command line. It only seems to give an empty response using guzzle through php

Comment: @pdizz - Are you sure that curl isn't setting a default `User-Agent` when running from the commandline?

Comment: @Cyclone I was wrong, It looks like guzzle is sending `Guzzle/3.8.1 curl/7.19.7 PHP/5.5.8` and curl is sending `curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.15.3 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2` for User-Agent

Comment: @Cyclone I changed the user agent string to `Chrome/40.0.2214.111` and I'm still getting and empty response body `GET /jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/projects/****/Resource/BulkShiftExport.csv?ACCOUNT_ID=*&START_DATETIME=2015-01-01&END_DATETIME=2015-01-31 HTTP/1.1
Host: jasper.i3app:8080
User-Agent: Chrome/40.0.2214.111
Authorization: Basic ****`

Comment: @pdizz - Edit you question and add code showing how you make your call using `guzzle`. Also add the commandline that is working.

Comment: I think we need to see how the cURL and the Guzzle **request headers** differ. It seems like you have discounted the User-Agent, maybe it is another?

Comment: @halfer Updated. The only difference I could see besides the User-Agent was `Accept: */*` being sent in the curl request. I tried adding that to the headers in the guzzle request but I got the same result.

Comment: Hmm, not sure (aside: your request URLs appear to be different, particularly for `END_DATETIME`).

Comment: Im wondering if this is an issue with guzzle/php writing to a different stream

Comment: From the guzzle docs `When more than 2MB of data is stored in a temp stream, it automatically stores the data on disk rather than in memory.` This report is over 2mb https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/blob/master/docs/http-client/entity-bodies.rst

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `MockHandler` mistakenly.